# Git-garbage retention time

Tags: git, version-control

I was trying to checkout a previous reflog hash after an accidental hard reset. Exactly for how long can GIT retain the reflog/ commits which were reset or garbage data?

Comment: Afaik git garbage collects commits which are unreachable (via a branch or tag) after 2 weeks. The ref log is a different matter (I don’t know). A reset doesn’t mean a commit will be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default it's 90 days, and you can configure it with [gc.reflogExpire](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#Documentation/git-gc.txt-gcreflogExpire).

Also, it doesn't get altered by `git reset` commands. `reflog` is your safety net.